# Open Wiki Page by ID and not by Name

Tags: 2013, wiki, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

Standard behavior of SharePoint Wiki: accessing the page via URL (containing name of page), e.g. SharePoint.com/WikiLibrary/NameOfThePage.aspx

I want to know if there is a possibility to access the page using the ID

I know it is possible to use DispForm.aspx?ID=123 but this opens the form and not the Wiki Page Layout

Use Case is that I want to provide links to dedicated pages from an external application - standard URLs can change if someone renames the page, calling a page via ID will not break in case of rename.

Anybody knows a possibility? Thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research I found an ootb possibility:

1. Enable "Document ID Service" in the Site Collection Features
2. New entry in the Site Collection Administration appears: "Document ID settings"
3. In this menu you can define a prefix for your Document IDs
4. In any list/library a new column is provided: Document ID (linked to document)
5. Display this column in a list view --> use the provided URL of this column for linkage

For information: 
the URL to be used looks like: 
yoursitecollection/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=DocIDPrefix-SomeNumbers-ID

yoursitecollection/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=DocIDPrefix-12345678910-1234